# Entity Framework slow first db connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

First connection to database in my app (EF 6.2, code first) is very slow,
is there a way to modify `OnModelCreating` part of my `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
            .Where(type => type.BaseType != null
            && type.BaseType.IsGenericType
            && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));

        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

In Debug mode I see that this is the reason that the initialize connection takes several dozen seconds...

Comment: "Several dozen seconds"? That seems excessive. How big is your context, do you have lots of `DbSet`s? How many items do you add in the configurations list in the code above? Do they do anything unusual?

Comment: I mean first connection takes some time... 4 DbSets, 4 Models, 4 Maps for this models inherits from EntityTypeConfiguration<Model>. Just started learning all this stuff... sometimes there are blockers like this. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The first Entity Framework Query is always slow because EF *compiles* your model and generates *mapping views* in memory.

You can pre-generate those mapping views using the EF Power Tools. Theres a documentation for that [here in learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/pre-generated-views).

In order to load those views you need to create a custom DbConfiguration class like this:

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration() : base()
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);
        SetModelStore(new DefaultDbModelStore(path));
    }
}
```

usage:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public class MyContextContext : DbContext 
{
}
```

More info on DbConfiguration: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based)

Something else that you can do if your application does **not run in Azure SQL** is to use a CustomManifestTokenResolver like this

```
public class CustomManifestTokenResolver : IManifestTokenResolver
{
    public string ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
    {
        return "2012";
    }

}
```

In order to use it you have to add it to your DbConfiguration Class

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration() : base()
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);
        SetModelStore(new DefaultDbModelStore(path));
        SetManifestTokenResolver(new CustomManifestTokenResolver());
    }
}
```

Another performance issue during startup is just-in-time-compilation of the EF Assemblies. You can use ngen to get around this (this assumes that your assemblies are located in the bin\release folder.

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen install .\bin\release\EntityFramework.dll
 %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen install .\bin\release\EntityFramework.dll
 %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen install .\bin\release\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
 %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen install .\bin\release\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
 %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen install .\bin\debug\EntityFramework.dll
 %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen install .\bin\debug\EntityFramework.dll
 %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen install .\bin\debug\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
 %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen install .\bin\debug\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

For general EF Performance issues I do have a [repository at github](https://github.com/AndreKraemer/EFPerformanceDemo) where I demonstrate common issues and solutions to those issues.

**Update: Added Startup Performance Trick**

Something that we use to do in our software is to execute an empty query during startup. Assuming that we have a Context Called `MyContext` and a DbSet called `Customers`, we would write something like this during startup:

```
using(var db = new MyContext())
{
   db.Customers.Where(x=> x.Id < 0).ToList();   // There are no negative Ids, so this will always be and empty list
}
```

This will move your initialisation code into the startup phase of your application. Because of this the user will not have a slow experience for the first real query in the system. You can even do that async. You just have to make sure that there are no other calls to your Context from other threads at the same time because DbContext is not ThreadSafe.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove reflection part and just give the types by hand. Reflection is slow task  , and you can't expect a fast experience with something that uses reflection, but because it's only for the first connection,I personally wouldn't care, if it's not that critical to start very fast.

Comment: What about put connection when app start ... something like "warming app" ?

Comment: Still,the app will start slow,that's not fixing the problem,that's masking the problem so that end user can't see that. If for the scenario it's good enough,it's easiest way to do that.

Comment: It _is_ something to care about if your program is a console util that must be run several times a minute. 